# How to convert multi-character constant to integer in C?

Tags: c++, c, char

> How to convert multi-character constant in x to integer?

I tried for example `'13'` as `('3' + '1' << 3)`, but it doesn't work properly.
I don't mean `"0123"`, but `'0123'`. It compiles, but I don't how did compiler gets the octal result 6014231063 when printing it.  I am not looking for `atoi` which just converts this to present number. For example `int x = '1'` would print 49 in decimal number system. Now I am interested what would print `int x = '0123'`. This task is from programming competition, so the answer shouldn't be unexpected behavior.

```
int main(void) { 
  int x = '0123';  
  printf("%o\n", x);
  printf("%d\n", x >> 24);
  printf("%d\n", x << 8 >> 24);
  printf("%d\n", x & 0xff);  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int x = '0123';` although obscurely legal, is not what you want --> `int x = 123;`

Comment: "it doesn't work properly." lacks detail.  What did you see, what did you expect?  When I run the code, I get what I see which _may_ be the same as you, may not.

Comment: ...or perhaps `int test = atoi("0123");`

Comment: @WeatherVane I honestly thought `int x = '0123';` wouldn't even compile. Obscure indeed.

Comment: Did you really mean a single *character* constant `'0123'` with multiple characters jammed into it, or did you perhaps mean `"0123"`?

Comment: @Bob__ curiously enough, it was chux who pointed that out to me previously - and he just commented soon after I did!

Comment: Hi, this is multi-character constant. I didn't mean "0123", but '0123'. It compiles, but I don't know how to convert it to int. I am not looking for atoi which just converts this to present number. For example int x = '1' would print 49 in decimal number system. Now I am interested what would print int x = '0123'. Answer is 6014231063 in octal number system, but how to get that? This is from one programming competition.

Comment: Please update your question to indicate more clearly exactly what you're looking for. Multicharacter constants are already of type `int`, and have implementation-defined values -- and they're really not very useful. What integer value do you expect to get from `'0123'`, and why?

Comment: Left-shifting certain signed integer values invokes undefined behaviour. right shifting is implementation defined. In total it is a bad idea.

Comment: And `'0123'` **is** an integer already.

Comment: Olaf, I updated question. I am looking what printf is going to print. And why?

Comment: @ProdajemDom, no one will tell you why. Such constants are implementation-defined, and you really need to look into some dark corners of documentation to find them (if you are lucky enough!). There is no 'why' here, it is simply the fact of life.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to convert multi-character constant to integer in C?

`'0123'` in an `int`.

```
int x = '0123';
```

---

`'0123'` is a *character-constant*.  In C, this is one of the forms of a constant and it has the type of `int`.  It is rarely used as its value is implementation-defined. It's usually the following depending on endianness and character codding (e.g. ASCII):

```
(('0'*256 + '1')*256 + `2`)*256 + '3' = 858927408 = 0x33323130
(('3'*256 + '2')*256 + `1`)*256 + '0' = 808530483 = 0x30313233
```

Further:  It is a challenge to write useful portable code with it.  Many coding styles bar it when used with more than 1 character.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Maybe, but it is what the OP *asked*.

Comment: Actually `0123` is the *c-char-sequence*. `'0123'` is a *character-constant*. (That's the C terminology; C++ probably uses different terms.) Also, nothing in the standard says that the number of characters in the sequence is limited to `sizeof (int)`.

Comment: @Keith Thompson What I meant to say was that the number of unique values that can be derived certain does not exceed `sizeof(int)` characters.  IAC, the details of multi-character constant are loose enough to prevent their general portable use: a legacy of C that lives on the same forlorned street as digraphs and tri-graphs. which is next to the dump of `=-` and `foo(...)`.

Comment: It is impossible to use it in portable code since the value is (explicitly) *implementation-defined* which is non-portable by definition. Digraphs are not forlorn imho; they are simple and usable. Trigraphs are deprecated and may disappear in some future standard.

Comment: @rici Hmmm,  If `char` is unsigned or signed  is _implementation-defined_, yet `char` used is wide-spread. I-D by itself does not equate to non-portable.  Perhaps posting a "how to use multi-character constant portably" may elicit an acceptable use?

Comment: @chux: For that reason, it is impossible to portably use character values outside of the range 0-127. Only non-negative values which could fit into a signed integer can be used *portably*. So it's no different.

Comment: @rici The same line of thought would encumber `double` to non-portability, given its underlying range, precision and other characteristics are not uniform.  C succeeds because it brings a high level of portability to divergent platforms both archaic and futuristic - not necessarily absolute portability as using  multi-character constant likely prevents.

Comment: @chux: The standard imposes reasonable minima for precision and range of `double`. By contrast, it imposes *no restrictions whatsoever* on multicharacter character literals. An implementation could choose to just use the first character, for example, and some do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105861/discussion-between-chux-and-rici).

Answer (score 4):

`'0123'` is a multi-character constant/literal (C calls it a constant, C++ calls it a literal).  In both languages, it is of type `int` and has an *implementation-defined* value.

It's *probably* typical for `'0123'` to have the value

```
('0' << 24) + ('1' << 16) + ('2' << 8) + '3'
```

(assuming `CHAR_BIT==8`, and keeping in mind that the values of `'0'` et al are themselves implementation-defined).

Because the value is implementation-defined, multi-character constants are rarely useful, and nearly useless in portable code. The standard doesn't even guarantee that `'0123'` and `'1234'` have distinct values.

But to answer your question, `'0123'` is already of type `int`, so no conversion is necessary. You can store, manipulate, or print that value in any way you like.

For example, on my system this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("0x%x\n", (unsigned int)'0123');
}
```

prints (after a compile-time warning):

```
0x30313233
```

which is consistent with the formula above -- but the result might differ under another implementation.

The "implementation-defined" value means that an implementation is required to document it. gcc's behavior (for version 5.3) is [documented here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/cpp/Implementation-defined-behavior.html):

> The preprocessor and compiler interpret character constants in the
>   same way; i.e. escape sequences such as `‘\a’` are given the values they
>   would have on the target machine.
>
> The compiler evaluates a multi-character character constant a
>   character at a time, shifting the previous value left by the number of
>   bits per target character, and then or-ing in the bit-pattern of the
>   new character truncated to the width of a target character. The final
>   bit-pattern is given type `int`, and is therefore signed, regardless of
>   whether single characters are signed or not (a slight change from
>   versions 3.1 and earlier of GCC). If there are more characters in the
>   constant than would fit in the target int the compiler issues a
>   warning, and the excess leading characters are ignored.
>
> For example, `'ab'` for a target with an 8-bit `char` would be
>   interpreted as
>   `(int) ((unsigned char) 'a' * 256 + (unsigned char)'b')`,
>  and
>   `'\234a'` as 
> `(int) ((unsigned char) '\234' * 256 + (unsigned char) a')`.

Comment: Something new to learn every day. Can I ask what are they used for?

Comment: @Bob__: Ideally, nothing. But I've seen them used as a kind of human-readable unique number (which works only if the values are actually unique).

Comment: Apple used to use them extensively (and maybe still do.) But it wasn't just Apple who used file and data formats with four-byte tags. You'll find "tagged" formats all over the place: image formats, font formats, video formats.... Using four ascii characters for the four bytes is a simple way of avoiding the need for huge numbers of symbolic constants.

Comment: @rici To add detail: .png files use 4-char tags - albeit in a very specified order.  Agree about avoiding the symbolic constants.

Comment: @chux: .png is an image format, ¿no? Although GIF and TIFF files (which came much earlier) are also both tagged formats with four-byte tags.

Comment: @rici: Yes, png is an image format, and PNG files start with `{ 0x89, 'P', 'N', 'G' }`. I don't think multi-character constants are going to be useful there.

Comment: @keithThompson. From the PNG format (https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#5Chunk-layout): "Chunk Type: A sequence of four bytes defining the chunk type. Each byte of a chunk type is restricted to the decimal values 65 to 90 and 97 to 122. These correspond to the uppercase and lowercase ISO 646 letters (A-Z and a-z) respectively for convenience in description and examination of PNG datastreams. Encoders and decoders shall treat the chunk types as fixed binary values, not character strings..."

Comment: For comparison, see [Wikipedia on Macintosh OSType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSType), from which I quote: "OSType  is the name of a four-byte sequence commonly used as an identifier in Mac OS. While the bytes can have any value, they usually [use characters, condensed to fit in comment]... FourCC is a system of data format identification used in some platform-independent multimedia containers, such as AIFF and RIFF. It inherits may codes from the OSType. A similar system is also used in TrueType font format." (I was wrong about TIFFs, though. TIFF tags are only two bytes.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something in the lines of creating a function like this:

```
int StringLiteralToInt(const char* string, int numbeOfCharacters)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int ch = 0; ch < numberOfCharacters; ch++)
    {
        float powerTen = pow(10, numbeOfCharacters - (ch+1));
        result += (int)string[ch] * (int)powerTen;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I just wrote that inline, so it might not be 100% right, but it should be the right idea. Just multiply the chars by a power of ten (right most - 10^0, left most - 10^(strinSize-1).

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Why go to all that trouble? Why not just use `atoi`?

Comment: Hi, I am not looking for atoi, I know how this works. Look into task it is '0123', not "0123". It is not string, it is multi-character constant.

Comment: Didn't know such a thing actually existed, but does sound exactly like what OP wants! EDIT: Apparently not what OP wants

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try this:

```
int main()
{ 
    int x = '0123';  
    printf("%x\n", x);
}
```

For me this prints `30313233`, as I expect.

Here it is broken apart, as it looks like you were trying to do:

```
    printf("%o ", (x >> 24) & 0xff);
    printf("%o ", (x >> 16) & 0xff);
    printf("%o ", (x >> 8) & 0xff);
    printf("%o\n", x & 0xff);
```

These printouts show that the multi-character character constant is, in some sense, made up of the characters `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'`, and `'3'` all jammed together.  But there is really no sense in which this multi-character character constant has any meaningful relationship to the *integer* `123`.  (We could write some code to shift and mask by 8 bits, then subtract `'0'` to convert from character to digit, then multiply by 10 and add, just like `atoi`, but it wouldn't really mean anything.)

Comment: Well, [this](https://ideone.com/U9urP5) prints 808530483, but I didn't expected...

Comment: How did you get 30313233? This is what I am interested in.

Comment: Downvoting for providing answer very similar to the one which Steve himself downvoted! Fair play.

Comment: @SergeyA: I was trying to help the OP see how to pick the integer apart, which seemed like what he was trying to do, but he has accepted that other answer, so I guess I was confused.  C'est la vie.

Comment: I see useful info here especially the octal part as that was in OP's post/comment.