# How to represent ObjC enum AVAudioSessionPortOverride which has declaration of int and string using Dart ffi?

Tags: objective-c, dart, ffi

I'm working on a cross platform sound API for Flutter.
We're trying to stop using Objective C/Swift for the iOS portion of the API and we're using Dart ffi as a replacement.

ffi(foreign function interface) allows dart to call into an Obj C API.

This means we need to create a dart library which wraps the Obj C audio library.

Whilst doing this we encountered the `AVAudioSessionPortOverride` enum which has two declarations; `AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker = 'spkr'` and `AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone = 0`.

I'm confused as to what's going on here as one of these declarations is an int whilst the other is a string.

I note that `AVAudioSessionPortOverride` extends an NSUInteger so how is the string being handled. Is it somehow being converted to an int? if so any ideas on how I would do this in dart?

Here's what we have so far:

```
class AVAudioSessionPortOverride extends NSUInteger {
  const AVAudioSessionPortOverride(int value) : super(value);

  static AVAudioSessionPortOverride None = AVAudioSessionPortOverride(0);

  static const AVAudioSessionPortOverride Speaker =
      AVAudioSessionPortOverride('spkr');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'spkr'` is in fact an int. See e.g. [How to convert multi-character constant to integer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35902421/how-to-convert-multi-character-constant-to-integer-in-c) for an explanation of how this obscure feature in C works.

That said, if you look at the Swift representation of the `PortOverride` enum, you'll see this:

```
/// For use with overrideOutputAudioPort:error:
public enum PortOverride : UInt {    
    /// No override.  Return audio routing to the default state for the current audio category.
    case none = 0

    /// Route audio output to speaker.  Use this override with AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord,
    /// which by default routes the output to the receiver.
    case speaker = 1936747378
}
```

Also, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/portoverride/speaker

Accordingly, `0` and `1936747378` are the values you should use.

Comment: Hi - would 'spkr' or some similar text based abbreviation work in Swift?

Comment: No, I don't think Swift supports this, and that's why the Swift implementation/documentation uses the resulting int value as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this

```
NSLog(@"spkr = %x s = %x p = %x k = %x r = %x", 'spkr', 's', 'p', 'k', 'r' );
```

Apple is doing everything your lecturer warned you against. You can get away with this since the string is 4 chars (bytes) long. If you make it longer you'll get a warning. The string gets converted to an int as illustrated in the code snippet above. You could reverse it by accessing the four bytes one by one and printing them as a character.

Spoiler - it will print

```
spkr = 73706b72 s = 73 p = 70 k = 6b r = 72
```